# Perforce: get ONLY the local path of a depot file

Tags: perforce

I need to get the local path of a depot file, for example:

```
input: //MyDepot/MyBranch/my file.txt

output (mac): /Volumes/p4/MyDepot/MyBranch/my file.txt
```

or:

```
output (windows): F:\p4\MyDepot\MyBranch\my file.txt
```

both 'p4 have' and 'p4 where' produce parse-unfriendly output, including mapping info I don't need. Is there a p4 command for that simple task?

Comment: `where` is the correct command, but you'll probably want to use it with `p4 -Ztag where` (or with `-F` and an appropriate format string).  See https://www.perforce.com/blog/fun-formatting for more details. (I don't have access to a Perforce instance to give you an actual answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a non-Windows OS, Run:

`p4 -ztag -F %path% where <depotFilePath>`

This will give you the one-liner with only the local path.

On Windows, %path% expands to the system environment path so this only works on non-Windows systems.

The -F is a client-side option, so if you don't have it, you may need to update your p4 binary. If you don't have it, and can't update the binary, you can also just run `p4 -ztag where <depotFilePath>`.

You'd get back easy to parse output. The key is `path` to get the local path to the file.

The output will look like:

```
... depotFile //depot/a
... clientFile //gabe/a
... path /Users/gabe/tmp/a
```

Comment: This is better, however still needs parsing. Is that as good as it gets?

Comment: Yup, there's no command that will just give you a one-liner of the path with nothing around it. Depending on your language, there are p4 APIs that will give you a marshaled object. So the Python SDK for example will give you an object that you can just call a la obj.path to get what you want, but that then involves a dependency on the p4 API which may or may not be overkill depending on what you're doing.

Comment: As I alluded to in my comment, something like `p4 -Ztag -F "%path%" where DEPOT_PATH` maybe could work. (I'm not completely sure if `%path%` is the correct format specifier, and if it is, it'd probably pose a problem on Windows.)

Comment: Perforce, I am unhappy about this! However parsing the ztag'ged output is a no brainer. Thanks.

Comment: jamesdlin is absolutely right. I'll amend my solution. It depends on server version to use the -F, so it might not always work, so I'll leave the other answer as well.

Comment: Sorry @jamesdlin I didn't see your comment before I answered!

Comment: Unfortunately %path% on Windows expands to the environment path... any way to escape this?

Comment: The `-F` is a client side option, so you have it even with old servers!

To escape the `%path%` string on Windows I think you can do `^%path%`.

Comment: Amended answer to include various pieces from these comments.

Comment: Bah, yeah, sorry. :(

Comment: @gil_mo You probably should file a bug with Perforce about their poor choice for a format specifier.  On Windows, you'll probably have to parse the output with `grep` and `cut` (or equivalents if you can't rely on them being available) or use the p4api directly.

Comment: Ok, filed a bug with Perforce, their frontline man is taking it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Very close, Samwise.   I would have made this a comment on the main answer, but not enough rep yet, sorry.

To prevent Windows from expanding the environment variable, both percents need to be carrot escaped, and that part of the expression must not be in quotes.

example: p4 -ztag -F ^%change^%,^%time^%,^%path^% changes -m 3

example from 2020/4/2: https://community.perforce.com/s/article/15148